# PHP - Environment Variables Not Available When Script Called From Cron Job / Command Line

Tags: php, apache, cron, environment-variables

My `test.php` file looks like:

```
<?php

echo $_SERVER["myEnvVariable"];
echo getenv("myEnvVariable");
```

The above will return my set environment variable twice.  It works when the script is called from outside the server.

If I call the same script on the server using the command line command:

```
php test.php
```

or using a cronjob

```
****** curl http://localhost/test.php
```

nothing is returned.

How do I make available my environment variables within the server itself?  I am setting my environment variables within the Apache `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: Is the env var set for the account you're logged in as when you're running from the command line? Because command line doesn't care what might be set in your apache configuration

Comment: If you're trying with http, and use the real url instead of localhost, do you get the env variables?

Comment: When you call it from the command line with the `php` command, you bypass Apache, which is why you don't get the env variable. Not sure how to get around it tho. @MarkBaker you should write an answer outlining how to set the var "for the account you're logged in as."

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables

Comment: Depends on the OS, but typically on Linux you can do `export myEnvVariable=myValue` at some point before calling `php test.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute the cron job this way:

```
myEnvVariable=value php test.php
```

Variable will be available from `getenv("myEnvVariable")`, not in `$_SERVER`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to make a special curl call to your file. Something like this:

**test.php** (this is your file, no changes here)

**specialcurl.php**:

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init('http://www.youraddresshere.com/pathtofile/test.php');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $result;
    curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Now, run with php command the specialcurl.php script from the server as:

```
php specialcurl.php
```

The point here is to call your test.php as a valid user calling your server. It works for me.

Comment: Good idea. It does require you to have the script publicly available however. By the way `file_get_contents('http://www.youraddresshere.com/pathtofile/test.php')` should do the same job in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you are having lots of environment variables try this,

**Export env entries to a file**

```
env >> /etc/environment
```

**Add the CRON job with** `crontab -e`

```
5,35 * * * * . /etc/environment; /usr/local/bin/php /srv/app/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

***CRON**: Running php scheduler at 05, 35 of each hour with source of all the environment variables. (replace with your command)*

Answer (score 1):

Try setting wget to http://address.domain/test.php in cron.
I know this isn't solution but might help.